# Слайдер swiper. Как исправить баг в IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, slider

Использую для верстки слайдер [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WCWLH7KLSUk). На одной из страниц сайта предполагается наличие большого количества блоков-товаров, в каждом из которых есть этот слайдер. В Chrome, Firefox и Opera все нормально, но IE, как обычно, что-то не нравится: при наведении на слайдер некоторое время отображаются все слайды карусели, хотя для родительского блока прописан `overflow: hidden;`. Посмотреть проблему "вживую" можно [здесь](http://cyprus.890m.com/Cyprus/sale.html).

Буду очень благодарен, если вы подскажете каковы причины такого поведения и как решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Попробуйте родительскому блоку `.result-item-slider-block` добавить `position: relative;` и `overflow: hidden;`. Начните с `relative`.
2. Версию браузера вы не писали. Попробуйте добавить `-ms-overflow-style: none;`.
   UPD:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Проблема у вас с transition. Добавьте overflow: hidden для этого класса: `.result-item-slider-container, .result-item-slider-container span`

Comment: Ваши рекомендации проблему, к сожалению, не решили.. IE11.

Comment: Пришлось поставить 11-ю версию. Вот сюда `.result-item-slider-container, .result-item-slider-container span` добавьте `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, вы меня спасли)

Comment: Немного поспешил я - поклацайте вправо/влево - слайдер некорректно работает..

Comment: Да, код довольно странно срабатывает. На вашем месте, я бы решил эту задачу убрав hover-эффект вместе с transition для IE. Если очень уж хочется, чтоб работала конструкция с увеличением изображения, можно реализовать его через keyframe.